# Query with join on first part of field

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have two tables with City names. One of them is only the city name, the other is city name including state. I need to build a reference table between both, so I want to join them on the first part of the field.

Now, my current method works, but is extremely slow, so I was wondering if there is a faster method.

Table 1 would be:

```
|'ID'|'City'|'Inhabitants'|
|1| New York|9576000|
|2| Boston|617000|  
etc.
```

Table 2 would be:

```
|'ID'|'City'|'Inhabitants'|
|1| New York - New York|9576000|
|2| Boston - Massachusetts|617000|  
etc.
```

My query is:

```
SELECT Table2.[City] as CityState, Table1.[City]
FROM Table2 INNER JOIN 
     table1
     ON left(Table2.[City], len(Table1.[City])) = Table2.[City]
```

Result is:

```
CityState|City
New York - New York|New York
Boston - Massachussetts| Boston
```

Hope someone knows a better way. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably LEFT ruins the use of indexes...? Is the query faster without LEFT?

Comment: Normalize the database...

Comment: Definitely recommend Florian's suggestion if at all possible. First Normal Form (1NF) requires that each field have one and only one piece of information; putting city and state in the same field, particularly when you're trying to extract only part of that, indicates that the database is not in 1NF.

Comment: yes, I understand. And this data by all means should be normalized. But just looking at the question: would there be another way to achieve?

Comment: I've had to take delimited lists and perform this sort of join before. Take a look at http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/06/sql-server-udf-function-to-convert-list-to-table/ and see if that will work for you.

Comment: Silly me: I didn't realize that you'd tagged this with MS Access. You may have to write VBA code to get anything that performs better than what you have.

Comment: You are not even break on rule of normalization but all of them it seems. Id strongly recommend fixing the design after reading up on the subject... then u can write views to get what you had before and go from there. Right now your heading is the worst part of hell

Comment: It is not my design. The thing is that I have to normalize the data I got thrown at me from different datasets.

Comment: Option1 in this case is writing some vba code and Option 2 is manipulating the data using some excel functions... depends on your expertise which is better. Id use option 2 for its fast and easy to test and adjust... import into a normalized structure and you are there